# Why THP (Transparent Huge Pages) are not recommended for Databases like Oracle and MongoDB?

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, oracle, memory-management

I'm curious to know the reason why transparent huge pages are not recommended for the Databases like Oracle and MongoDB? How THP affect the performance of any Database?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/

Comment: Not sure if THP is the same thing as HugePages, but if so they are recommended for Oracle: https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/configuring-huge-pages-for-oracle-on-linux-64

Comment: @WilliamRobertson THP is the improvement to the traditional HugePages. There is difference between the two. HugePages are allocated at boot time but THP are allocated dynamically. A kernel thread (khugepaged) runs in background to manage HugePages.

Comment: It sounds like the same advantages should apply. Who is saying it's not recommended for Oracle? I'm not a DBA or sysadmin though. I think this should probably be on https://dba.stackexchange.com or https://serverfault.com.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson on your shared link, Huge Pages are recommended but THP (Transparent Huge Pages) are not.

Comment: 1st there was u bug in Linux kernel, that made khugepaged stuck for a long time. This made Oracle processes unresponsive (event RAC ones having realtime priority). 2nd THP are swappable, while normal HPs are not.

Comment: @DesiHacker - Oh, you are right. I didn't read that far down the article. Does it answer your question?

Comment: The MongoDB tutorial on [disabling THP](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/) has a relevant blurb: `Transparent Huge Pages (THP) is a Linux memory management system that reduces the overhead of Translation Lookaside Buffer (TLB) lookups on machines with large amounts of memory by using larger memory pages. However, database workloads often perform poorly with THP, because they tend to have sparse rather than contiguous memory access patterns. You should disable THP on Linux machines to ensure best performance with MongoDB.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's because THP are swappable, and the Linux `swap` subsystem can only handle base page sizes and not HugePages. This creates a race condition which has a significant impact on system performance.

This [Oracle blog dates from 2014](https://blogs.oracle.com/linuxkernel/improving-the-performance-of-transparent-huge-pages-in-linux,-by-khalid-aziz) but still seems to be the final word on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Modern machines have not only `enable` or `disable`, there is also an `madvise` setting. All machines that I checked have the latter as default already(!) for the enable and defrag setting.
Check

`cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/{enabled,defrag}`

According to the definition of madvise, this disables THP by default, but allows applications to ask for THP support via an madvise() call.

Maybe the suggestions from 2014 are no longer relevant?

https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/03/06/settling-the-myth-of-transparent-hugepages-for-databases/ has a newer discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

According to the link below, Oracle has also recommended disabling THP.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ladbi/disabling-transparent-hugepages.html#GUID-02E9147D-D565-4AF8-B12A-8E6E9F74BEEA